# Privileges Access to moderator tools wrong reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, privileges

In the [Access To Moderator Tools](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), just above 'Inline tag editing', it says the standard 10K rep (for non-beta sites) instead of the beta 2K rep.

It says:

> Finally, as a **10K+** member of the site your opinions likely carry quite
>   a bit of weight with your peers: if you see a trend that you think is
>   worth calling attention to, don't hesitate to do it - having access to
>   more data makes it easier to back up your assertions.

But it should say:

> Finally, as a **2K+** member of the site your opinions likely carry quite
>   a bit of weight with your peers: if you see a trend that you think is
>   worth calling attention to, don't hesitate to do it - having access to
>   more data makes it easier to back up your assertions.

[image]

---

@Oded has fixed this. It now says (as Gilles suggested):

---

> Finally, as a **high-reputation** member of the site your opinions likely carry quite a bit of weight with your peers: if you see a trend that you think is worth calling attention to, don't hesitate to do it - having access to more data makes it easier to back up your assertions.

Comment: Thanks @Oded for fixing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that it's a bug. This should just say “high-reputation”: it reads better, and it's easier technically since the text is shared between sites.